# Zeta functions on q-deformed compact Lie groups

Tags: zeta-functions, quantum-groups

I’m reading some of the recent works on representation zeta functions for groups. Along the way, I have also explored some of the remarkable properties of Witten zeta function. I’m wondering if there are any study along the line of zeta functions on q-deformations of “nice” compact Lie groups or for q-deformations of universal enveloping Hopf algebras. Thanks in advance.